# Is this json file well parsed?

Tags: json

I would like to know if the following message is well parsed according to json format, I think it is but the application that needs to process it complains about it with the following error

> [ERR]tx data JSON file error

The code in the file is this one

```
{"tx":
{
    "moteeui":"fa789f0000000000",
    "txmsgid":"000000000152",
    "trycount":"5",
    "txsynch" : "false",
    "ackreq" : "true",
    "userdata":
    {
        "port":"10",
        "payload":"ABCABC"
    }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance,

regards!

I have tried also the following snippet

```
[{
    "mote": "202020",
    "payload": "ABCB",
    "port": 2,
    "trycount": 5,
    "txmsgid": ""
}]
```

I have validated with JSONLint and I get an error saying

```
[ERR]tx data JSON parsing error: 3 object item(s) left unpacked
```

Does it ring a bell?

Thanks again

Comment: If you don't show us the parsing code, we can't tell if it's correctly parsed. The JSON is valid at least.

Comment: when in doubt, www.jsonlint.com (or other). Yes, your JSON is valid, so you will need to give more context to your question.

Comment: Thanks @TimCastelijns and YvesLeBorg , well I cannot really see how the parsing is being made, I only have access to the log which is that obscure...

Comment: Perhaps the tool that is parsing the JSON is expecting certain variables to be present. You will need to consult the documentation for whatever tool you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct.

For your info, [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) is a good site for checking the validity of JSON.

However, you may want to rethink setting numeric values as strings. ie, it is a better idea to say:

```
"trycount":5
```

rather than

```
"trycount":"5"
```

As the former indicates to whatever application is consuming the JSON that the value should be parsed as a number.

Similarly with the boolean values, it's better practise to use:

```
"txsynch" : false
```

rather than

```
"txsynch" : "false"
```

It won't cause an error in your JSON parser to pass these as strings, it is just better practise.

The error in the parser could be for many different reasons.

Comment: Note that while it's indeed better practice to use booleans to represent booleans and same for integers, putting them in strings would not cause and error during the parsing.